# Installing Antivirus on Hyper-V Guest and Host Systems

Tags: anti-virus, active-directory, hyper-v, windows-domain, symantec

I have one physical server which runs two Hyper-V Servers. One is for SQL Server and the other is Domain Controller.

I want to install Antivirus on these servers with exclusions added.

Is it advisable to run antivirus on these three machines?

All machines are sharing same NIC. Will it affect network performance when network is monitored by both Host and Guest Machine's Antivirus ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/441214/should-i-enable-firewall-and-antivirus-on-a-virtualpc-vm, http://superuser.com/questions/115147/does-it-make-any-sense-to-install-anti-virus-on-windows-xp-mode, http://superuser.com/questions/68528/does-anti-virus-work-while-working-on-a-virtual-machine

Comment: That's not my question. I need to know whether the NIC will be scanned by both Antivirus. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007